# Monitor/Log slow running queries in Apache Cassandra 2.2.X

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.2

how to monitor/log slow running queries in Apache Cassandra 2.2.X version without using any external monitoring tools? Is there is any parameter that we can set in YAML to log slow running queries? or any other approach?

Also in CASSANDRA-12403, i see they added parameter "slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms: 500" for this purpose. Can we add this parameter in Cassandra 2.2.X version's Cassandra.YAML file? or do we need to apply this patch for 2.2.X version in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Its a feature in a newer version, you can upgrade or apply the patch and go off of a custom build. In 2.2.x theres no support to do it by itself.

Its a bit of a long shot but you might be able to get https://github.com/smartcat-labs/cassandra-diagnostics with https://github.com/smartcat-labs/cassandra-diagnostics/blob/dev/cassandra-diagnostics-core/COREMODULES.md#slow-query-module to work. It also only supports 2.1 and 3.0 though, I dont see 2.2 there.